Interaction of endogenous variable with binary predictors (feols)
I would like to inquire about the correct way to specify interactions of endogenous variable with binary predictors (time and treat) with the feols function.
Ideally I would like to specify a 3 way interaction between a treatment variable (2 categories), a time variable (2 categories), and the endogenous variable. But for now I've decided to go with a 2-way interaction with only the time variable and partition my data into treatment and control sub-samples.
feols(Y ~ time + other exos | FE | endo:time+endo ~ IV:time+IV, data, 
          cluster= ~ CL)

Should I add the main effect of time in the first part formula?
And if I further split my samples into pre-post and treatment-control, how would the interpretation of coefficient on the endogenous variable differ in comparison to running the above interaction.
